# Using git checkout with make/ninja-like tools efficiently

Tags: git, makefile, ninja

When i work with my git-repos(in C/C++), I switch branches regularly and sometimes would like to build a specific branch or tag(using make). When I switch back to my currently-mostly-in-focus branch, running make will result in very long build-times. Is there some way to configure git, or use some git-checkout specific arguments to restore the state of the repository as far as the build system(e.g make) is concerned? Is the build system ninja better at this?

If there is no way of doing this, then why? If there is a way of doing it, why is it not implemented by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main question is why your build tool needs that much longer. If it is because the files that are different between the branches need to be rebuilt, how should the build tool or Git prevent this? You can use `git worktree` to add have multiple worktrees for different branches if that is your problem.

Comment: Will check out worktrees, never heard of them. Doubt they are the solution at first glance, as they seem more closer to git stash. I think my question is probably more basic since I am still pretty new at this

Comment: It has not the least in common with stashing. It simply allows you to have multiple worktrees for different branches. (A worktree is your actual checked out working files) So to switch branches, you simply go to another filesystem location, where your built files should still be up-to-date

Comment: will check it out before I make any more ill-informed comments then... like for example saying "that sounds like cloning" :)

Comment: Implying that you would want to say "that sounds like cloning", it really sounds more like cloning than stashing, but not really. cloning clones the full repository with its full history. `git worktree` just creates a new directory with checked out files from a different branch, working on the same local repository.

Comment: so, if get it right: a bare repo has 0 worktrees, a vanilla flavor repo (as produced by clone) has 1 worktree, and you can add as many as you like (as much as your hard-drive and/or sanity permits you) using git-worktree.

Comment: Exactly. There is one restriction, you can checkout a branch only in one worktree at the same time. If you have checked out master in one of the worktrees and try to checkout master in one of the other worktrees, you get an error message. But it is super-cheap to create a branch, so if you need two worktrees for the same branch, you might need to either create a second branch on the same commit (the `worktree` command can do this when creating the worktree) or checkout a detached HEAD of the branch, meaning the worktree has the files of that branch checked out, but you cannot commit to that...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "the state of the repository as far as the build system is concerned"; I assume what you're saying is you change to another branch, then without building switch back - but doing this changes the timestamps on source files so make thinks it has to rebuild everything...

The simplest solution IMO would be to use two work trees - one that you keep on your "usually-in-focus branch", and one for browsing around other branches.  This can be done either by cloning the repo twice, or using the `git worktree` commands.

I'm not aware of any way for git to set the source timestamps to what they were before you switched branches.  Why not?  Because implementing that in a way that is generally useful without causing problems would likely be impossible.

Comment: Well, with state of the repo, as far as the build system go... I guess that would be the time stamps of all the source files, the finished binaries and intermediate object files. I have purposefully put those files(edit: binaries and object files that is) in .gitignore... is that something that would be doable: put git tracking on those files? I am pretty new to using git as you may guess.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger It **is** impossible, because imagine you build a newer branch, then switch to some older branch. If timestamps would be preserved, all input files would be older than the output files and thus timestamp based up-to-date checks would be impossible. For this cause a change in the actual file needs to update the timestamp to **now**. If the situation is like you described, switching to a better build tool like Gradle would be a solution that does not rely on timestamps, but on checksums of input and output files.

Comment: You are correct to put finished binaries and intermediate files in .gitignore; if git tracks those it will cause problems.  It wouldn't really fix the problem anyway, because the timestamps still won't show the relation between source files and binaries.  The thing is, a freshly checked-out work tree should be freshly rebuilt really.  So I'd reiterate that best solution IMO is to have a separate work tree for browsing other branches.

Comment: @StefanKarlsson No, that would not work, besides that you should **never** put built artifacts into VCS it would not work anyway as timestamps are not preserved and cannot be preserved.

Comment: Seems like git working trees are really worth checking out. Seems it could be the right answer. Will get informed and get back to (probably) accept that answer. @Vampire s answer was a few minutes earlier...